# Adjustment of text inside \tcolorbox and getting rid of ident after box

Tags: formatting, tcolorbox

I have following chunk of text:

```
\begin{tcolorbox}[boxrule=0pt,arc=0pt,colback=gray]
tar: Ignoring unknown extended header keyword 'SCHILY.fflags'\\
tar: Ignoring unknown extended header keyword 'SCHILY.fflags'\\
tar: Ignoring unknown extended header keyword 'SCHILY.fflags'\\
tar: Ignoring unknown extended header keyword 'SCHILY.fflags'\\
tar: Ignoring unknown extended header keyword 'SCHILY.fflags'\\
tar: Ignoring unknown extended header keyword 'LIBARCHIVE.xattr.security.capability'\\
tar: Ignoring unknown extended header keyword 'LIBARCHIVE.xattr.security.capability'\\
tar: Ignoring unknown extended header keyword 'LIBARCHIVE.xattr.security.capability'\\
tar: Ignoring unknown extended header keyword 'LIBARCHIVE.xattr.security.capability'\\
tar: Ignoring unknown extended header keyword 'LIBARCHIVE.xattr.security.capability'
\end{tcolorbox}
```

And screenshot represents latex output of this text.

[image: tcolorbox output].

First 6 lines are formatted ok, but next lines are not ok, how do I align them properly (to the left)? And after box, in text, I have indent that I do NOT want to have. How do I fix it?

Comment: And `\noindent` before the paragraph after the box.

Comment: Try increasing the width of the text block.

Comment: @Mico It is already `\textwidth` hence increasing with is not a good idea.

Comment: @HarishKumar - But the width of the text block can be increased locally, right? :-) The solution given in your answer -- to reduce the font size locally -- is even better, though.

Comment: @Mico Yes it can be increased by the option `oversize =<length> `option or `enlarge left by` and `enlarge right by` options.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `flushleft upper` as the option to `tcolorbox`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tcolorbox}[flushleft upper,boxrule=0pt,arc=0pt,colback=gray]
tar: Ignoring unknown extended header keyword 'SCHILY.fflags'\\
tar: Ignoring unknown extended header keyword 'SCHILY.fflags'\\
tar: Ignoring unknown extended header keyword 'SCHILY.fflags'\\
tar: Ignoring unknown extended header keyword 'SCHILY.fflags'\\
tar: Ignoring unknown extended header keyword 'SCHILY.fflags'\\
tar: Ignoring unknown extended header keyword 'LIBARCHIVE.xattr.security.capability'\\
tar: Ignoring unknown extended header keyword 'LIBARCHIVE.xattr.security.capability'\\
tar: Ignoring unknown extended header keyword 'LIBARCHIVE.xattr.security.capability'\\
tar: Ignoring unknown extended header keyword 'LIBARCHIVE.xattr.security.capability'\\
tar: Ignoring unknown extended header keyword 'LIBARCHIVE.xattr.security.capability'
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With some font size and margin (left & right) adjustment like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
  \noindent
  Some text
  \begin{tcolorbox}[fontupper=\footnotesize,flushleft upper,boxrule=0pt,arc=0pt,left=2pt,right=2pt,colback=gray,after=\ignorespacesafterend\par\noindent]
tar: Ignoring unknown extended header keyword 'SCHILY.fflags'\\
tar: Ignoring unknown extended header keyword 'SCHILY.fflags'\\
tar: Ignoring unknown extended header keyword 'SCHILY.fflags'\\
tar: Ignoring unknown extended header keyword 'SCHILY.fflags'\\
tar: Ignoring unknown extended header keyword 'SCHILY.fflags'\\
tar: Ignoring unknown extended header keyword 'LIBARCHIVE.xattr.security.capability'\\
tar: Ignoring unknown extended header keyword 'LIBARCHIVE.xattr.security.capability'\\
tar: Ignoring unknown extended header keyword 'LIBARCHIVE.xattr.security.capability'\\
tar: Ignoring unknown extended header keyword 'LIBARCHIVE.xattr.security.capability'\\
tar: Ignoring unknown extended header keyword 'LIBARCHIVE.xattr.security.capability'
\end{tcolorbox}
Some text here
\end{document}
```

you get this:

[image]

To stop indenting after the box, you can use `after=\ignorespacesafterend\par\noindent` as the option to `tcolorbox`.

Comment: I did not get your result, I am sure the path is right, that I confirmed the answer, but your result is perfect, but I did no get it.

Comment: @MarkoFrelih Is your `tcolorbox` upto date? Can you update and try again?

Comment: It is, I've updated it!

Comment: @MarkoFrelih Does it work then?

Comment: No, I did not get your result, sorry for invalid answer before!

Comment: @MarkoFrelih Then you have to make a complete MWE (starting from `\documentclass` and ending at `\end{document}`) and append it to the question or ask a separate question. Whichever you do please don't forget to ping me.